# Check if mail and password is wrong on ReceivedHttpAuthRequest android WebView

Tags: android, webview, authorization

Iam trying to set password and username  it working fine when i add valid password and user name i want to check if this details are wrong where can i detect that it's wrong ?!!!

I tried to use on error but not working fine with me

```
    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    private boolean error;

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
            HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {

        handler.proceed(userName, password);

    }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            error = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest   request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
          //here i am trying to detect wrong password but no thing happen
            }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError( WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)  {

            //here i am trying to detect wrong password but no thing happen
            error = true;
            System.out.println("description error" + description);
            view.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (!error) {
                view.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            }
            error = false;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


        return true;

    }


}
```

Comment: Did you solve this?  I really need the answer :)